# HighStock setExtremes in angular HighStock

Tags: angular, highcharts

i created **HighStock** chart using some data.in stock chart **xAxis range selector select full range of data.** but I need to select custom size showing when its creating time without clicking any button. after some search, I found **setExtremes** is the way for it. but I don't have any idea how its use in **angular componenent**. I tried lots of ways but no luck.
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-6ly2j?file=/src/main.ts

[image: HighStock setExtremes angular]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 st method** 
give **xAxis min and max** Values 
**live demo-:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-stock-kctkpk?file=app/app.component.ts

**2 nd method** 
Using **setExtremes**
to use setExtremes in angular we need to specify callbackFunction for get created chart instance. [highchart github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#callbackFunction-details)

 
**live Demo:-** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kqfpl8?file=src/app/app.component.ts